# Azure Pipelines builds visual steps not my .yml file

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I created an azure pipeline to build a VS (c++) project and using the visual editor I got it all working, then I used the yaml they suggested and added the azure-pipelines.yml file to my project and added a trigger.

When I commit a build a process is started up, but it's using the steps I created in the visual editor, not what is in .yml file. I actually have it starting two jobs in the .yml (OSX and Windows) and sure enough, both jobs are started but they are ignoring all the -step's in my .yml and instead execute the steps in the visual editor.

I'm perplexed.

Here is a chunk of the .yml file...

```
trigger:
- master

jobs:
- job: Mac
  pool:
    name: Hosted macOS
    demands:
    - cmake
    - xcode

  steps:

  - task: CMake@1
    displayName: 'CMake "Xcode" Release'
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: '_buildOSX'
      cmakeArgs: 'bla bla bla'

  - task: Xcode@5
    displayName: 'Xcode build'
    inputs:
      xcWorkspacePath: '$(Parameters.xcWorkspacePath)'
      scheme: '$(Parameters.scheme)'
      xcodeVersion: '$(Parameters.xcodeVersion)'
```

SNIP

```
- job: Windows
  pool:
    name: Hosted VS2017
    demands:
    - cmake
    - msbuild
    - visualstudio

  steps:
   - task: CMake@1
    displayName: 'CMake "Visual Studio 17" Release'
    inputs:
      workingDirectory: '_buildWin'
      cmakeArgs: 'bla bla bla'
```

SNIP

Again, the trigger executes and it starts 2 jobs as listed, but it doesn't run the steps in the .yml file.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. It turns out you have to use Github.  Building from the .yml file doesn't seem to be supported using bitbucket (or a 3rd party git remote).

There might be a way around it, but it was easier to mirror my repo on Github and all works now.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration has to be done while creating a pipeline.

After selecting the repository in VSTS pipeline creation, 
select YAML configuration and provide the path for pipeline.

[image]